# problema con ruteo de express js?

Tags: express, router

tengo un problema el cual de que quiero hacer aparecer en la pantalla un json object
les dejo el codigo del archivo de rutas y el de el server, aclaro que no se como crear servidores estoy aprendiendo a base de seguir un tutorial en youtube paso a paso, pero luego de revisar varias veces que tenga el codigo igualmente escrito no entiendo por que me salta este error:

index.js

```
//Estos van a ser los imports

import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import usersRoutes from "./routes/users";
// App y puerto
const app = express();
const PORT = 5200;

// Middlewares

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/users', usersRoutes);

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server running on port: http://localhost${PORT}`));

// Routes

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello from Homepage'));
```

Este es el users.js

```
// Imports

import express from "express";

const router = express.Router();
const users = [
    {
        name: "Nicolas",
        lastName: "Garrasini",
        age: "26",
        email: "nicogarrasini@gmail.com",
        userName: "",
        password: ""
    }
];

// Todas las rutas de aca van a apuntar a '/users'
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(users);

    res.send('Hello');
});

router.post();
export default router;
```

Me devuelve este error: node:internal/process/esm_loader:94
internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\nicog\Documents\workspace\NiQuiz\routes\users' imported from C:\Users\nicog\Documents\workspace\NiQuiz\index.js
Did you mean to import ../routes/users.js?
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:404:11)
at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:963:10)
at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1172:11)
at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:580:30)
at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:294:18)
at ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:80:40)
at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:78:36) {
code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

Comment: "_me salta este error_": Nunca pones el error. ¿Por qué tienes un `router.post();` sin nada ahí puesto?

Comment: Por otro lado, tal vez estás siguiendo un tutorial antiguo. Desde hace ya bastante tiempo, `body-parser` viene integrado en `express` y no necesitas instalarlo como dependencia. Saludos

Comment: Agregue el error a la pregunta, disculpen.
router.post() porque iba a probar los ruteos con postman pero no llegue a nada porque me tira ese error

Answer (score 0):

Agrega a tu importación de `users.js` la extensión del archivo `.js`. Eso solucionará tu problema:

```
import usersRoutes from "./routes/users.js"
```

Recuerda eliminar o completar la instrucción incompleta que colocaste `router.post();`. Por otro lado, considera remplazar `bodyparser` por el middleware que ya trae `express` por defecto. El `index.js` quedaría:

```
import express from "express";
import usersRoutes from "./routes/users.js"

// App y puerto
const app = express();
const PORT = 5200;


app.use(express.json())
app.use('/users', usersRoutes);

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello from Homepage'));

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server running on port: http://localhost${PORT}`));
```